# Angular - Generate component to body tag

Tags: angular

I try to generate a component to the root element.

Currently, I have found some resource which is close to what I want, but using the  `DynamicComponentLoader` which is **deprecated**.

```
public component: any;

constructor(
  public dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, 
  public _injector: Injector, 
  public _elementRef: ElementRef
) {
}

public click() {
  if(this.component != undefined){
    this.component.then((componentRef:ComponentRef) => {
      componentRef.dispose();
      return componentRef;
    });
  }

  this.component = this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(Form, this._elementRef);
}
```

Here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aCYwHEuVlxsyBGxnLAmr?p=preview).

The result is the template is generated outside of  `my-app` tag, but it only works because the code is inside `my-app` tag's component, and it generates the new element to its sibling.

[image]

Now my question is : what is the current way to generate a component to the body tag, without have to reference it inside templates ?

Here the kind of template output wished :

Before click :

```
<body>
    <app>
         <button (click)="click()">
    </app>
<body>
```

After click :

```
<body>
    <app>
         <button (click)="click()">
    </app>
    <my-directive>
         ...
    </my-directive>
<body>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Is this what you want? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html#

Comment: mmm sorry can't you poot another tag (like <my-app-two></my-app-two> ... outside the <my-app></my-app>) and then create another component which is binded to it?

Comment: @wannadream Indeed it looks like, but the is a reference to the directive `ad-host` ! How do I reference the body instead of the directive `ad-host` ?

Comment: @federico scamuzzi Hum, the fact is with your idea, the directive will be behind another tag, I need to have my component generated right behing the body, like `<body><app>...</app><my-directive></my-directive></body>`

Comment: you may put <ng-template> to where you want.

Comment: It relies on viewChild, so you can't reference a directive inside a parent isn't it ? And moreover, I would like to not reference the component inside templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass your app's `ViewContainerRef` to another component to be used as a rendering target.

Store your app component's `ViewContainerRef`:

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

Pass it to another component:

```
<form-renderer [target]="viewContainerRef"></form-renderer>
```

Render the form next to the app component:

```
export class FormRenderer implements OnInit {
    @Input('target') target: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // You may need to do this inside a setTimeout

        let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Form);

        this.target.createComponent(componentFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I have shared the `viewContainer` to a global service, so I won't have to pass it to every component, and it works so well ! Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome. Was it necessary to use `setTimeout` or some other workaround? Sometimes creating views inside hooks like `ngOnInit` causes errors.

Comment: No I didn't have too. Maybe if I got the problem I will use `onAfterViewInit` instead of `onInit` !