# How to do Angular2 works in <body>?

Tags: angular

I created this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1NeiZa46YkfqIbcL0UHW?p=preview) to show my current situation. In this example there is nothing wrong, but I would like `<h1>` in index.html also shows in the application.

Currently:

```
Hello Angular! v4.1.3
Hello World!!!
```

My intention result should be

```
loading my name is Angular! v4.1.3
Hello Angular! v4.1.3
Hello World!!!
```

I know that I could remove and put this `<h1>` to any component, but it's not what I want and I need my application running in `body`.
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Never seen anyone attempt to do that. Probably because its not a good practice or possible. This is how component design should be: https://plnkr.co/edit/g7v8Jae0LwrmFpKoU9J5

Comment: I agree that it's probably not good practice. But it looks like it can be done if you absolutely need it. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985671/angular-generate-component-to-body-tag/43986922#43986922) I showed how to use the app component's `ViewContainerRef` as a rendering target. When you call `createComponent` on it, the new component is created adjacent to the app component (directly inside the body tag).

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AppSecondaryComp);
    const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }
}
```

Just make sure to register `AppSecondaryComp` in the `entryComponents` array of your module.

Does this work for you? `app-secondary` would be rendered right inside the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ng-content>`, but not in "root" component (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4946). For example, if in `index.html` you do

```
<body>
   <app>Loading...</app>
</body>
```

app.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <h2>Hello {{user.name}}</h2>
        <app-secondary><h3>Some content</h3></app-secondary>
    `
})
```

app-secondary.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-secondary',
    template: `
        <div>
            <h2>Hello World!!! </h2>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
     `,
})
```

Rendered page will be:

```
<body>
    <app>
        <h2>Hello Angular! v4.1.3</h2>
        <app-secondary>
            <h2>Hello World!!! </h2>
            <h3>Some content</h3>
        </app-secondary>
    </app>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<body>` tag in the index.html is where Angular bootstraps initial component. Because it's a SPA, basically the whole application's view will be rendered within this `<body>` tag.

You have to make your desired changes in the template of the boostraping component, which is inside the `src/app.ts` file.

See the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EGw69njeCrtHt6giMCxI?p=preview) here

Comment: Hi @Nehal thx. I know that, but it's exactly what I won't, because in my real case I really need it in `<body>` tag and angular able to interpret it there.